# How to update individual nested components mapped from a state array of nested objects, without re-rendering everything?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm new to React and working on an app (using React hooks) that is basically a clone of a Trello board or Kanban board, so a set of lists displayed as columns, where each list has a number of cards. The user can add new lists and add new cards to a list (in addition to dragging and dropping cards from list to list) and that's where I'm having trouble.

When this view loads, I populate a state variable `lists` with an object from a database in the form of a array of list objects each with an array of card objects, basically structured like this:

```
[
  { 
    listId: 0, 
    listTitle: 'List Title', 
    cards: [
      {
        cardId: 0,
        cardText: 'some text'
      },
      {
        cardId: 1,
        cardText: 'some text'
      }
    ]
  },
  { 
    listId: 1, 
    listTitle: 'Another title', 
    cards: [ ... ]
  },
  { 
    listId: 2, 
    listTitle: 'Yet another', 
    cards: [ ... ]
  }
]
```

My components responsible for this view look basically like this:

```
function Board() {

  const [lists, setLists] = useState([]);

  const addList = (listTitle) => {
     // adds list to db and updates lists state with new array
  }

  const addCard = (listId, cardText) => {
    // adds card to db and updates lists state with new array
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    api.getLists()
    .then((listData) => {
      setLists(listData)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
    
  }, []);

  return (
    <main>

      {lists.map((list) => <List key={list.id} listId={list.id} title={list.title} cards={list.cards} addCard={addCard} />)}

      <AddElementPanel addElement={addList} />
    </main>
  );
}


function List({ title, cards, listId, addCard }) => {
  return (
    <section>
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <ul>
        {listCards.map((card) => <Card key={card.id} text={card.text} />)}
      </ul>
      <AddElementPanel listId={listId} addElement={addCard} />
    </section>
  );
}


function Card({ text }) {
  return (<li>{text}</li>);
}
```

My question is, when a user wants to add a new card or list, the data gets inserted into a database, but as is the only way I know how to show the changes is by doing something like `setList[...newList]` which of course causes every list and card to re-render. This seems not ideal to me, because if I'm adding a new list or a new card to one list, the unchanged lists will re-render. I know that's not a big deal for this current setup, but if something really expensive needed to happen in the child components, or there was a ton of data, how could this be structured better?

From researching, it seems like something like Redux or another state management library might manage state like this more efficiently, though I'm not 100% sure if that's accurate for a case like this having not yet learned Redux. I'm also curious if there is a simpler solution, or a better way to set things up in the first place that would prevent this behaviour? I tried wrapping the List component in React.memo, but that didn't seem to make a difference so I'm either doing it wrong or not taking into account something that is affecting it. Would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: The classic way of doing something like this is to send the new card into database behind the scenes while updating the UI client-side. In other words, just draw the new card client-side and have it saved behind the scenes in the database without reloading anything. Furthemore this might be a use-case for KEYS (https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) which tell react internally to map the elements rendered from array to your DOM in a smart way so that only the changes get rendered, but not everything.

Comment: @Swiffy Yes, this is exactly what I am trying to do, but I can't figure out how to do it with the way I have things set up, or how to set them up differently. I do have unique keys set on both lists and cards. My UI of lists and cards all come from parts of that one state object `lists` passed down as props. So if I wanted to just append one card in the UI for example and leave the `lists` state alone, how could I do so?

Answer (score 0):

Did you do any performance tests that made you suspect that you're having unnecessary rerenders with this code? AFAIK, [React's diffing algorithm](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#the-diffing-algorithm) handles this as long as you're using unique keys in your components.

In fact, `useMemo` shouldn't add any improvement here since its dependencies would change every time the lists/cards array changes.

Comment: So right now I simply have a console.warn() in the render for List and Card components, and those do fire every time I update the lists state, which indicates to me that code is being run. But if I turn on Rendering > Paint Flashing in DevTools it seems like not everything is repainted. So does that mean this is a completely fine way to do things? I'm trying to prep for coding interviews so generally knowing how to optimize even simple examples is pretty important.